# Determine current host location e.g. Europe/London

Tags: go

I'm developing a client application that will run on our user's servers. I'd like to make a guess at the current location e.g. America/New_York or Europe/London to relay to the service so it can compute current time on the client with respect to UTC offset and daylight saving rules.

Any thoughts on how the app could best guess at current location? I know I can get the current timezone like "PST" but that doesn't tell me what I need to know.

Comment: Have you looked at `Location`: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky If I do e.g. time.Local.String() I get "Local" -- do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Corrected, JimB. Thanks

Comment: You can only guess, and you won't know when you're wrong. Trying to maintain data from different timezones between timezones always leads to confusion, so I always recommend using UTC exclusively. Most servers are configured as UTC anyway, so there's probably nothing to guess.

Comment: I coucur with @JimB: while you can do `time.Local.String()` and hope for the best (especially on Windows), it's best to not *expose* this information in any data exchange happening between geographically disparate computers. While it's okay to have non-UTC locale on the machine running your software, make sure that it converts all the time it sends outside to UTC. Or *at least* make sure you're using timezone-aware external (on-the-wire) representations for the timestamps you send—such as `time.RFC3339`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu (and probably other Linux distros), `/etc/timezone` contains a description of the location (e.g. `Australia/Sydney`), if one was set when the server was setup. As has been mentioned in the comments, there is no guarantee this is going to be correct.

If you have internet access you could do a GET request to `https://freegeoip.net/json/` or something similar which will return a json object containing geolocation data for your ip. Again, there are many things that could affect the accuracy of this.

The code below does both these things, note for brevity there is no error checking (which is bad).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type LocationData struct {
    IP          string  `json:"ip"`
    CountryCode string  `json:"country_code"`
    CountryName string  `json:"country_name"`
    RegionCode  string  `json:"region_code"`
    RegionName  string  `json:"region_name"`
    City        string  `json:"city"`
    ZipCode     string  `json:"zip_code"`
    TimeZone    string  `json:"time_zone"`
    Latitude    float64 `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude   float64 `json:"longitude"`
    MetroCode   int     `json:"metro_code"`
}

func main() {
    // Using /etc/timezone
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/etc/timezone")
    fmt.Printf("%s", buf)

    // Using freegeoip
    var locationData LocationData

    resp, _ := http.Get("https://freegeoip.net/json/")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    decoder.Decode(&locationData)

    fmt.Println(locationData.TimeZone)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh. This is roughly what I've resorted to already, with a quick check of TZ environment variable, and I'm looking to parse output of timedatectl which will work on FreeBSD as well. But I was really hoping somebody had done this cross platform stuff already and I Just hadn't found it.